# Removing repeated page numbers from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Hi I'm trying to create a document in LaTeX with a few small subsections on the same page, is there any way to remove the repeated page numbers and keep the numbers when I move onto a new page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I've no programming skills, it seems obvious that this possible; e.g. by adding a hook before each line of the toc: "if the pagenumer is the same as in the last line, print dots and number in `\color{white}` ".

There are some packages on CTAN regarding the table of contents. Do you know the "Topic Index"? Have a look on the packages about the table of contents [there](http://texcatalogue.sarovar.org/bytopic.html#toc).

The closest candidate seems to be the package `tocloft`. If you've got a full installation, you might get the manual by typing `texdoc tocloft` on the command line. Maybe you can use `\cftXleader` or something similar.

However, your readers will miss the numbers and ask themselves (they can not ask you, can they? they are reading in a book!), whether it's a typo or not. So take my advice: print the 'toc' like all others do . . .

Comment: These are all okay workarounds, but I think I will leave it, and change the subsections to headings. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to do this using the `tocloft` package.  The idea is roughly that proposed by Keks Dose, but here are the correct details and a concrete implementation.

You need to redefine the `\cftXfillnum` macro, where `X` stands for the relevant section levels, whose numbers you don't want displayed, and at one level above.  Each of these needs to store the relevant page number in a some variable.  The lower entries need to test the current value against the stored value and act accordingly.

In this example I have assumed you want all sections to be numbered, but subsections and subsections under those with common page numbers are not numbered.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\makeatletter
\def\currentcontentsnumber{0}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfillnum}[1]{
  {\cftsecleader}\nobreak
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]{%
  {\cftsecpagefont #1}}\cftsecafterpnum\par
  \gdef\currentcontentsnumber{#1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfillnum}[1]{\expandafter\ifx\currentcontentsnumber#1
  \hfill\nobreak\else
  {\cftsubsecleader}\nobreak
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]{%
  {\cftsubsecpagefont #1}}\fi
  \cftsubsecafterpnum\par
  \gdef\currentcontentsnumber{#1}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecfillnum}[1]{\expandafter\ifx\currentcontentsnumber#1
  \hfill\nobreak\else
  {\cftsubsubsecleader}\nobreak
  \makebox[\@pnumwidth][\cftpnumalign]{%
  {\cftsubsubsecpagefont #1}}\fi
  \cftsubsubsecafterpnum\par
  \gdef\currentcontentsnumber{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage
  \section{Lorem ipsum}
    dolor sit amet
    \subsection{consectetur adipiscing}
      elit. Donec a diam lectus.
        \subsubsection{Sed}
  \section{sit amet}
   ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue[...]
\newpage
  \section{ligula}
    ac quam viverra[...]
    \newpage
    \subsection{nec}
\end{document}
```