# Removing redundant TOC page numbers in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

The question of removing redundant page numbers [ie, where a page is repeated follows another in the table of contents in a work with short sections on the same page] is addressed here ([Suppress redundant page numbers in the toc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266552/suppress-redundant-page-numbers-in-the-toc)) and here ([Removing repeated page numbers from table of contents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64078/removing-repeated-page-numbers-from-table-of-contents)) but the replies to both deal with `tocloft` and I can’t get them to work with `memoir`. Is it possible to do this in `memoir`?

So, I desire this code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\clearpage
\section{Test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsection{test}\clearpage\subsubsection{test}\section{test}
\subsection{test}\section{test}
\end{document}
```

which currently produces

[image]

to instead produce: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `tocloft` and `memoir` are by the same author, most `tocloft` solutions will work with `memoir`, but with slightly changed names. Roughly, where `tocloft` uses abbreviated sectioning names like `chap`, `sec`, `subsec` etc., `memoir` usually use the full version of the name. So here's the approach shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/266552/2693) adapted to `memoir`. You need to apply the patch to each sectioning level that you want it to work at.  In your case, since you don't want the page number displayed at all, there's no need to make the code use `\textcolor{}` at all, but I've left that option available in the commented code.

Since the original code (which is not originally mine) effectively uses the displayed page number, it fails if the numbering is not arabic, which means that if you put `\frontmatter` in the document, it will fail, since the page numbering is set to roman. I've now fixed this and cleaned up the code substantially to deal with repeated roman or arabic page numbers.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\settocdepth{subsection}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% this function from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/427559/
\prg_new_protected_conditional:Npnn \if_is_int:n #1 { T, F, TF }
  {
    \regex_match:nnTF { ^[\+\-]?[\d]+$ } {#1}% $
      { \prg_return_true: }
      { \prg_return_false: }
  }
\int_new:N\l_clrize_svpage_int
\int_set:Nn\l_clrize_svpage_int{0}
\NewDocumentCommand{\resetsvpage}{}{\int_set:Nn\l_clrize_svpage_int{0}}
\cs_new:Npn\clrize#1{
\if_is_int:nTF{#1}
    {\int_set:Nn\l_tmpa_int{#1}}
    {\int_set:Nn\l_tmpa_int{\int_from_roman:n{#1}}}
\int_compare:nNnTF{\l_tmpa_int}={\l_clrize_svpage_int}
    {}
%   Instead of the previous line, use the next line
%   to change the colour of the page number instead
%   {\textcolor{white}{#1}}
    {#1\int_gset:Nn \l_clrize_svpage_int {\l_tmpa_int}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xpatchcmd\cftchapterfillnum{#1}{\clrize{#1}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\cftsectionfillnum{#1}{\clrize{#1}}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\cftsubsectionfillnum{#1}{\clrize{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\mainmatter}{\addtocontents{toc}{\resetsvpage}}


\makeatother
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\mainmatter
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Test}
\clearpage
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\clearpage
\subsubsection{test}
\section{test}
\subsection{test}
\section{test}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: The code seems not to work when `subsection` is followed by `section`? https://imgur.com/a/16YFDog

Comment: @ezgranet You need to apply the patch to every level you want it to apply to. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you! One other point—it seems to break down if `\frontmatter` is set? Triggers missing number errors with `frontmatter` content

Comment: @ezgranet I've updated to the code to work properly with both the `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` page numbers of the contents.